# Cannot drag window in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mouse

For some reason, when I click on the title bar of any application window in my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS laptop, the window will NOT move.  This started happening after the last update.  What I have to do is right-click on the title bar and click the MOVE option then I can move the window. When googling for a solution I could not find one except for years ago on previous versions and then some said it was a GNOME DESKTOP issue and other an Ubuntu issue.

Has anyone else run into this issue?  If so, can you please provide some help/instruction on how to fix this issue?  I have a Logitech USB wireless mouse.  I never installed its driver into Ubuntu, it just always worked.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the solution you found for GNOME desktop? That might still be relevant as Ubuntu 18.04 in fact uses GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: Might it be that "all" Windows are maximized? Double click the title bar to disable/enable it.

Comment: Pornsky - no I didn't yet.  I was hoping that someone might have a solution for 18.04.1.  I'll try and see if any fix it.

Comment: Hannu - none of my windows are maximized.